# openntf domino api don't work

Tags: api, lotus-domino

I have domino designer 9.0.1

I want to use the openntf domino api but i can't find this file : com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;

I install the org.openntf.domino.jar of the OpenNTF Domino API M4.1
it find it

I install org.openntf.domino.xsp.update.zip of the org.openntf.domino API M4.5

but i can't do that :

```
    package test;

import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;
import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext; <= CAN'T FIND

public class UtilEssai {

    public String essaiMethode() throws NotesException {
          String texte = null;      
          Session session = Factory.fromLotus(NotesContext.getCurrent().getCurrentSession(), Session.class, null);
          texte = "Bonjour " + session.getCommonUserName();
          return texte;
    }
```

how i install and more how find this file ??
Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix jar and plugin versions. Plugin itself should be enough to work with the API.

Comment: when i use only plugin, it can't find all the import, it is because i add the jar.

Comment: see http://domino1.qtzar.com/org.openntf.domino/index.html?overview-summary.html for the javadoc. To get the session you could simply use Factory.getSession()

Comment: to make sure you have it installed ok, go to the xsp properties of your NSF and find out if you have org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary checked in XPage libraries

Comment: i'ts ok i have the library org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary and  checked in xpages librairies

Comment: i try to do Session session = Factory.getSession(); It's ok but when i run it, i have this error : "LS2J error : threw notesException : Cannot create a session from an agent". Sorry if the question is stupid but i was begginner with lotusdomino. I know java but domino...

Comment: ok, so simply remove the failing import and get session via  Factory.fromLotus(ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession(),Session.class, null)

Comment: that missing NotesContext class you're referring to is not part of the API

Comment: well i try to do with ExtLibUtil but i don't want, i have the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library in xpages librairies

Comment: i know that the NotesContext class is not part of the API but i try everything to work it ^^ . and i can't...

Comment: this is Agent you're talking about? not Java class in Code/Java? Then you need to put jar file to the agent. see https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/Using-the-API:-Agents

Comment: it 's a class in a ScriptLibraries (Code/ScriptLibraries/libEssai.javalib); i download this jar and i install it thanks !

Comment: Please be aware that there is a memory leak if you attach jar files to agents or Java script libraries...! If you call that code often enough it will crash the JVM of the server. But if you deploy jar files in the ext lib of the JVM instead then it works fine - and stable

Comment: first thanks a lot for your answer ! in reality i use my javacode in libraries and/or in web service. I put the jar in the ext lib of the jvm but only the jar of the openntf. you say there is a problem if i call my code or the api code ?

Comment: as it doesn't work with web service , i try with a library... but in the two case it doesn't works ... I am very bored !! I must to work with service web : i have an attribut private Session session and in my main () : session = WebServiceBase.getCurrentSession(); it's work very well but there is memory leak... so i try with the api and i don't find !! an idea to help me ?

Comment: i recycle but with the api normaly you don't do the recycle and it's better, and the recycle is more efficient in this case !!